# UpdatePanel slow server reaction

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I have an updatepanel which displays or hides a new control when I click a checkbox. But the problem is that is is very slow. From the click of the checkbox until the visual reaction occurs almost 2 seconds are gone.

I think this is due to the asynchonous callback. The client seem to wait 1-2 between each callback to fire. Is this true? If yes, is there a setting which makes callbacks to the server occur in instant time?

**EDIT** It seems i've hit a known bug, but the offered fix doesn't work for me:
http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2000262

Comment: there is no "setting". do you know what an updatepanel does? it posts everything inside it to the server (including viewstate). how long would it take you to refresh the page using the "refresh" button - almost 2 seconds. it has nothing to do with the callback, put less elements in the UpdatePanel, do less in the code-behind, etc to improve the performance. of course if you provide us with some HTML, as well as what is happening in your Page_Load event, we might be able to help.

Comment: Reduce if possible the items that are inside the panel. You can also use an inspector to see what send and how long its take to react and get them. (google chrome have inspector, also firefox have)

Comment: slap a spinning gif in an updateprogress control and call it good.

Comment: re your edit - IE and .NET 3.5 bug? wow. good thing i use neither of those products anymore (.NET 4 / Chrome FTW)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the `UpdatePanel` of DevExpress solved the problem in its latest version.